# Tax Deduction under section 80C for Indian with foreign family Paying International Premium

Tags: taxes, income-tax, tax-deduction, india

I am Ronit, indian holding indian passport.

My family, my wife and kids are foreign nationals and holding foreign
passport. I have purchased insurance from AIA and I am paying insurance
premium for my family.

Now I am moving to india with family, and i want to continue AIA plans. 
Can I show the premium paid and education fees as deduction for tax exemption?

Regards,
Ronit

Answer (score 1):

To claim tax benefit in India, the policy should be approved by Govt Agencies and the Company itself be approved.

I don't think foreign insurance companies would qualify for this.

More details here

http://law.incometaxindia.gov.in/dittaxmann/incometaxacts/2008itact/section80d.htm